# Permissão de schema em usuário específico

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Criei um banco de dados padrão e criei alguns schemas dentro deste banco de dados. Criei usuários para cada schema, agora quero dar permissão total para cada usuário em seu schema somente, como devo fazer?

Comment: Douglas, já associou User ao Login ? No SQL Server ambos são diferentes

Comment: Já sim, usei este comando: create user xx for login xx with default_schema= [xx];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma forma simples será assim:

```
GRANT TAKE OWNERSHIP ON SCHEMA::Person TO USER_1
```

Tens de ver que nivel de permissões queres dar ao user em questão, podes retirar todas as duvidas neste URL [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Properties do seu SCHEMA > Na aba esquerda carregue em permissions > click em Search (para procurar o utilizador) > logo em baixo estão as permissões do utilizador sobre o Schema